# How to keep persistent ftp connection in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sails.js

Can you please help me make a connection persistent script. I used jsftp node module to connect to ftp server. What I need to do is to check if the user is already authenticated every time he send a request. Thanks in advance! here's my code:

```
var Ftp = require('jsftp');

var dumpLog =  function (event){
        console.log('Code: '+ event.code);
        console.log('Message: '+ event.text);
}

var FtpController = {

    index : function (req , res) {
        res.view('ftp/login');
    },

    auth : function (req , res){

        // Initialize some common variables
        var user = req.param('user');
        var pass = req.param('pass');

        var ftp = new Ftp({
            host: req.param('host'),
            port: req.param('port') // Defaults to 21
        });

        ftp.auth( user, pass, function (err , auth_res){
            if (err) throw err;

            dumpLog(auth_res);
        });

        res.view('ftp/folder');
    },

    serve_folder : function(req,res){
        res.view('ftp/folder');
    },

};
module.exports = FtpController;
```

Comment: You need to use sessions to know the user logged in/successfully authenticated. Never used sailsjs, do you have anything like that in sailsjs ?

Comment: @user568109 yes sailsjs have session. :) im currently playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do stuff like this is probably a policy, since you'll want to be able to apply the check to various controllers as you build out your app.  Here's what your policy might look like:

```
// policies/ftpAuthenticated.js
module.exports = function loginToFTP (req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.ftpAuthenticated) {
    // Onward!
    next();
  }
  else {
    // authenticate here (we assume it works in this example)
    var success = true;
    if (success) {
      // Track that the user is connected via ftp for next time
      req.session.ftpAuthenticated = true;
      // save the connection object
      req.session.ftp = theFTPConnectionThing;
      next();
    }

    // if an error occurs, use the default error handler
    else {
      next( new Error('Sorry, an error occurred authenticating with FTP') );
    }

  }
}
```